# How do I reference the values for specific paths in a multiline D3 graph?

Tags: d3.js

I'm populating a graph with multiple lines and trying to access the highest values, then incrementing them every few seconds.  I'm not sure what syntax to use to access each line separately...

index.html:

```
function generateVisualization(data){

  //className for first timeline
  var className = "ch1Class";

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.price = +d.price; // +  ensures its an integer
  });

  maxY = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }));
  obj[className] = maxY;
  maxX = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  objD[className] = maxX;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return Math.max(d.date); })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return Math.max(d.price); }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("d", area)
      .attr("class", className);

  //make sure the first textbox is selected in the channel selection

  $("#demo_box_1").attr("checked","checked");

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", className)
      .attr("d", area2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);

}


<!-- time series start -->
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

//var parseDate = d3.time.format("%x %X.%L").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")//smooths path corners
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

var area2 = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")//smooths path corners
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.date); })
    .y0(height2)
    .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.price); });

var svg = d3.select("#maincontent1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "timeLine");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

var dataset;  //global variable

d3.csv("ch1.csv", function(error, data) {

  dataset = data;
  generateVisualization(data);

});

<!-- time series end -->
</script>

</div><!-- end #maincontent -->
```

included js file:

```
//create an object to track max y values
var obj = {};
var objD = {};


// if adding/removing paths check max values and rescale if necessary
function maxValue(maxY,maxX,addRemove,className){

    //if adding and its not in the array yet, then add to array, then check to see if its got the highest yvalue, if so updateaxis
    if(addRemove=="add"){
        if((className in obj )!=true){
            // add new class/max value to an object
            obj[className] = maxY;
            objD[className] = maxY;
            //check to see if its the highest yvalue in the object and if so, rescale
            var max = 0;
            for(var i in obj){
                if(obj[i] > max) {
                  max = obj[i];
               }
            }
            if (max==obj[className]){
                updateAxis("y");
                //reScaleEverything();
            }
            // important, reset the y domain to the new max, if you don't do this then the brushing will use the last added paths y max
            y.domain([0, max]);
        } 
    }  else if (addRemove=="remove"){

        //if its being remove then it should already have a matching obj, remove it from the obj array and then test for the new max yVal, rescale to new max
        if((className in obj )==true){
            var max = 0;
            for(var i in obj){
                if(obj[i] > max) {
                  max = obj[i];
               }
            }
            if (max==obj[className]){
                delete obj[className];
                delete objD[className];

                var max = 0;
                for(var i in obj){
                    if(obj[i] > max) {
                      max = obj[i];
                   }
                }
                //set the new y domain
                y.domain([0, max]);
                //y2.domain([0, max]);

                //rescale y using the new max value
                updateAxis("y");
            }
        }
    }


}

// found in maxValue(), this is called after setting domains
function updateAxis(axisXY){
    if (axisXY == 'x'){//Update x-axis
    svg.select(".x.axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(xAxis);
    } else if (axisXY == 'y'){
    //Update y-axis
    svg.select(".y.axis")
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .call(yAxis);
    }

    // very important, rescales all existing paths to new y values
    focus.selectAll("path").attr("d", area);
    //focus.selectAll("path").attr("d", area2);

    //focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}

function rescaleEverything(){


}

function checkSetY(maxY){
    var max = 0;
    for(var i in obj){
        if(obj[i] > max) {
          max = obj[i];
       }
    }
    if(maxY>max){
        //if the new maxY is bigger then any other Y then set a new domain
        return y.domain([0, maxY]);
    }
}
function checkSetX(maxX){
    console.log(maxX);
    var max = 0;
    for(var i in objD){
        if(objD[i] > max) {
          max = objD[i];
       }
    }
    if(maxX>max){
        //if the new maxX is bigger then any other Y then set a new domain
        return x.domain([0, maxX]);
    }
}

function addCSV(csvFileName, className){

  d3.csv(csvFileName, function(error, data) { 

          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.price = +d.price;
          });

          maxY = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }));
          checkSetY(maxY);
          maxX = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
          checkSetX(maxX);
          //x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
          //y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);

          x2.domain(x.domain());
          y2.domain(y.domain());

          focus.append("path")
              .datum(data)
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
              .attr("d", area)
              .attr("class", className);

          context.append("path")
              .datum(data)
              .attr("class", className)
              .attr("d", area2);

          // important, this fixes brushing issues, avoids multiple context brush areas
          context.selectAll("g.x.brush").remove();

          context.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x brush")
              .call(brush)
            .selectAll("rect")
              .attr("y", -6)
              .attr("height", height2 + 7);

            maxValue(maxY,maxX,"add",className);
                //maxX = d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return Date.max(d.date); }));
            //console.log(maxX);


        });
}

function removeCSV(className){
    var classRemoval = "." + className;
    d3.selectAll(classRemoval).transition().remove();
    maxValue(maxY,maxX,"remove",className);
}

function brushed() {
  x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
  //console.log(x2);
  focus.selectAll("path").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis); 
}

function incrementDate(){

    //pass in last date

}

$(document).ready(function() {

//addCSV("sp501.csv", "timeLine2");

    //toggle the side panel sliding
    $(".togglePanel").click(function(){
        //$("#channels").animate({left:'-130px'},350);
        var $lefty = $("#channels");
        $lefty.animate({
          left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
            -$lefty.outerWidth() :
            0
        });
    });

    $("#maincontent2, #maincontent3").hide();

    $(".gauge").hover(
        function(){
            var idName = $(this).attr('id');
            var newName = "." + idName.substring(0,3) + "Class";
            //alert(newName);
            $(newName).css("fill","#c2c2c2");
            $(newName).css("fill-opacity",".7");
            //$(newName).css("stroke-width","3");
        }, 
        function(){
            var idName = $(this).attr('id');
            var newName = "." + idName.substring(0,3) + "Class";
            $(newName).css("fill","none");
            $(newName).css("stroke-width","1");
        }
    );

    //hide all gauges
    $(".gauge").hide();
    //this one starts already open
    $("#ch1GaugeContainer").slideDown();

    $("#tabs li").click(function() {
        $("#tabs li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

    $('#channelSelect :checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var channelName = $this.attr("value") + ".csv"; 
    var className = $this.attr("value") + "Class";
    var guageName = "#" + $this.attr("value") + "GaugeContainer";
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        addCSV(channelName,className);
        $(guageName).slideDown();
    } else {
        removeCSV(className);
        $(guageName).slideUp();
    }

});


});
```

Comment: Are you importing multiple csv files (formatted with date,price) or can /are you importing a file with multiple values assigned against a single date row (date, price1, price2, price3). If you can do the latter then you should be able to select the maximum with a d.price1, d.price2 etc as  you already do with d.price in your code. Or possibly you could combine the data in php before loading so that it all gets loaded as a single file (although i expect that's not going to be your favorite option). More to follow in the next comment...

Comment: If I could make a suggestion. Parse your code down to the simplest version that will work on-line and post it up in github / gist. Really trim the extra goodies out of it (thanks for the offline link to the trial page, that looks awesome) so that the problem is really obvious and then it might make a bit more sense to me. Sorry to say I think I still don't fully understand the problem yet.

Comment: Thanks for putting the time in.  I'll work on getting a simplified gist version.  My approach might be storing the results of each csv import in separate global objects so they never terminate and I can keep referencing them.  I'm doing it with the first csv in the generateVisualization() function.  But I'm guessing that's improper memory hogging...  Its just a demo right now so I can get away with some duct tape solutions :)

Comment: Great! Good option. While I'm sure the data manipulation could be done in d3 somehow, it would probably be better practice to do it server side in a php script or similar? Either way, for the sake of a demo, the duct tape will suffice till a more elegant solution rears its head :-).